# Showing a throbber during html page load and rendering

Tags: html, rendering, throbber

I have a page that renders slowly.  The trip across the net is quick.  The initial load of the page is quick.  You can actually see (if your machine is slow enough), the initial layout of the html components.  Then some javascript stuff runs, making some of those components all ajaxy.  Then finally the css gets applied.

I can't do anything about the javascript that's slowing everything to a crawl.  So I need a throbber to tell the user to hold up, the browser is working.  Is there any way to trap the browser is done rendering event?  Is there even such an event?  Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You may want to do an age check before you start showing your 'throbber' on the interwebs.

Comment: I was initially excited, but then disappointed and confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show the throbber before the code is run and hide it after.

Using JQuery:

```
$("#throbber").show();
/* Your AJAX calls */
$("#throbber").hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

Check to see when the DOM is ready before calling all your Ajax stuff.

using [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org):

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  //your code
});
```

using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      //your code
});
```

Comment: Okay, this ok for showing the the throbber, but I can't figure out how to stop showing the throbber.

Comment: Once your code has completed loading the additional assets, hide the throbber.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/throbber